# animating shape keys

Tags: shape-keys

I recently learned shape keys and made couple of them. However the hard part for me now is animating them. Once I set values to 1 and key them and do the same for another facial keys nothing happens when I play the animation. Any solution. I'd prefer some image tutorial but not a must.

Comment: It's kind of hard to know exactly what's wrong from your description. Please add a blendfile and/or screenshots of your scene. You can add you blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the desired *frame* on your *timeline*, hover the cursor over the shape key's value and press <kbd>I</kbd>.
[image]

Go to another *frame* on a *timeline*, change the shape key's value to ***1.000*** and press <kbd>I</kbd> again.
[image]

Comment: Umh it tells me "active shape keys index property can't be animated.

Comment: You hover the cursor over the shape key's name. Hover it over the shape key's value. I've edited the answer to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To animate a shape key you need to set 2 keyframes. Normally, the first keyframe should have a value of 0 and the second a value of 1, although the values you set depend on the effect you are trying to achieve. Hope this helps..

Comment: What if that doesn't work??